# Xamarin.Forms - Difference between Label.TextProperty.PropertyName and nameof(myLabel.Text)

Tags: c#, properties, xamarin.forms, nameof

Besides the syntax, is there *any* difference between:

```
Label.TextProperty.PropertyName //(Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty.PropertyName)
```

and

```
nameof(myLabel.Text)
```

?

Comment: `nameof` is evaluated at compile-time. I don't know what `PropertyName` is in your example but it looks like a run-time call to get the name. Since it's a run-time call, it may choose to return the name formatted differently.

Comment: We would need to know what ProperyName is. It is not clear at all with the code provided.

Comment: Oops, that's a Xamarin.Forms property, not C# \*facepalm\*. Voting to close question.

Answer (score 0):

nameof(someObject.someProperty) gives you the name of the property (someProperty)

calling someObject.someProperty returns a value, which is defined in the property, so if u have a property like `int myProperty {get;set;}` it will return an object of type int. The int-type has no property or function like propertyName you can call.

The only case i know where comeObject.someProperty.ProeprtyName will not fail is when the property someProperty returns an object of the type PropertyInfo.

You can get PropertyInfo for every Property via reflection.

```
foreach(var propertyInfo in someObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    string propertyName = propertyInfo.PropertyName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nameof` is processed by the compiler into a constant string and thus incurs no runtime cost.

The second example, `someObject.someProperty.PropertyName` doesn't appear to be valid C# but, were it valid, would be computed at runtime and incur a cost at runtime. It is invalid because there is no `PropertyName` property that resides on every property (say that a few times fast).

The closest thing I can think of that looks similar to your second example is the `Name` property on a `PropertyInfo` object. For example, `typeof(MyThing).GetProperty("MyProperty").Name`. But that wouldn't solve your issue because it hardcodes the string `"MyProperty"`.